# Facebook log in with Realm throws status code 400 error

Tags: swift, facebook, realm

I logged in with Facebook and then used this code:

```
let facebookCredentials = SyncCredentials.facebook(token: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

SyncUser.logIn(with: facebookCredentials, server: Constants.Realm.Server) { (user, error) in
    if let user = user {
        print("\(user)")
    } else if let error = error {
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

and it outputs:

> Optional(Error Domain=io.realm.sync Code=3 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={statusCode=400})

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to discount this as a potential incorrect data issue, what is the value of `Constants.Realm.Server`?

Comment: `http://something.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9080`

Comment: Okay. That seems fine. Hmm. The Realm Object Server does attempt to verify that the Facebook token is indeed valid against the Facebook graph API. Are you able to verify it's valid on your end? If so, then this might actually be a bug and may need to be reported on Realm's GitHub.

Comment: @TiM, Found out the problem, it was a mistake from me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I skipped [this part](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#facebook) of the documentation which requires you to enable the Facebook authentication on the server by editing the `configuration.yml` and then `sudo service realm-object-server restart`.